# Why do we need GET method for API endpoint?

Tags: api, http-post, http-get

A general question of mine who working on API endpoints as backend system.

I wonder what if all endpoint methods are [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)), and when it is better to use [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585

Answer (score 0):

From this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46639/248616)

> Use **GET** for **safe and idempotent** requests
>
> Use **POST** for **neither safe nor idempotent** requests

So I can say that it's fine to go all for POST method.